# What should I do when I have 2 diferent edits for the same "object"

Tags: icons, grid, inline-edit, edit

So in my use case I have a list of objects in a sidebar and the rest of the screen is a grid with different elements in there. I can modify them with the edit mode. There is one icon for every object to inline edit (change name of the object and the color), and the other edit will change the position and size (number of squares on the grid).

[image]

- So should I have different labels?
- Should I use the same icon for both actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the first edit button necessary?

- By clicking on the color square the color is editable
- By clicking on the text field, the text is editable
- By clicking on the entire area, both elements are editable

Comment: hmmm good question... we have 2 different modes depending on the user role and for one its possible to enable all fields editable. I will try that. thanks for your answer.